# solution to replace value of database using matlab

Tags: java, matlab

How can I convert this java code to matlab code,
I want to update value of specific cell in database using matlab
please help TT

```
                    con2 =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/database","root", "  ");    
                    str = con2.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);


                    String selectlastdb = "select * from table order by id desc limit 1";
                    result = str.executeQuery(selectlastdb);

                    result.next();



                    result.updateString("aa", "hello");
                    result.updateString("bb", "bye");


                    result.updateRow();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB can directly use Java (unless you're running without the JVM), see more in the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/creating-and-using-java-objects.html). You should be able to reuse most of your code:

```
import java.sql.*;

con2 =  DriverManager.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://localhost/database','root', '  ');
str = con2.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

selectlastdb = 'select * from table order by id desc limit 1';
result = str.executeQuery(selectlastdb);

result.next();

result.updateString('aa', 'hello');
result.updateString('bb', 'bye');

result.updateRow();
```